# Is it better to call function in a nested way or to split each passage inside a var?

Tags: php

Take these three examples:

**ONE**

```
return lowercaseKeys(json_decode(trim($json),true));
```

**TWO**

```
$trimmed = trim($json);
$array = json_decode($trimmed,true);
$return = lowercaseKeys($array);
return $return;
```

**THREE**

```
$return = trim($json);
$return = json_decode($return,true);
$return = lowercaseKeys($return);
return $return;
```

Aside from readability, which is the best performance wise?
What is considered best practice?

p.s. code is only an example, not related to the question, I just copy pasted from my notepad window.

Comment: For performance, you can test yourself. Put each in a loop and time the runs (using the [`microtime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function) over a couple thousand iterations. Personally, if I'm only going to use something once, then I don't like making a variable for it. But 2 or 3 makes it easier to debug/error check later, if necessary.

Comment: @jswolf19, that's not a particularly good test as the result could be heavily optimized unless the input changed (and even then it could be heavily optimized if linearly executed)

Comment: @gamen, frankly, I'd be surprised if there were a lot of difference between the three considering the string parsing going on in `trim`, `json_decode`, and `lowercaseKeys`. If extra variables can affect the time appreciably over all that, then I don't think php would be as widely used as it is. And if the result gets optimized, anyway, then worries about which is better performance is moot, anyway, is it not?

Comment: My point is that calling the same code n times in an *isolated* fashion will not produce a representative timing result. Once that code is running alongside a bunch of other code, the timing will presumably change quite dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

Number one rule is do whatever is most readable when dealing with micro-optimizations. But here is a small test I did.

```
<?php
$iterations = 1000000;
$tests = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$json = json_encode($tests);

foreach ($tests as $function) {
        echo $function;
        $start = microtime(true);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $iterations; $i++) {
                $function($json);
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        echo ' - ' . ($end - $start) . " sec\n";
}

function one($json) {
        return array_change_key_case(json_decode(trim($json),true), CASE_LOWER);
}
function two($json) {
        $trimmed = trim($json);
        $array = json_decode($trimmed,true);
        $return = array_change_key_case($array, CASE_LOWER);
        return $return;
}
function three($json) {
        $return = trim($json);
        $return = json_decode($return,true);
        $return = array_change_key_case($return, CASE_LOWER);
        return $return;
}
?>
```

Results:

```
one - 3.3994290828705 sec
two - 3.5148930549622s sec
three - 3.5086510181427s sec
```

Option one is indeed a *tiny* bit faster, but that was one *million* iterations, and the time difference still wouldn't even be noticeable. With smaller amounts of iterations, the timing is too variable to even have a pattern to declare one better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, I don't think you'd really notice any difference. Would be minuscule...

But I vote for `option 2`, because it's the easiest to read (as opposed to `option 1`), and I don't think it's a good idea to keep overwriting it like you do in `option 3` (not very good form).

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference performance wise in your example.

Comment: Actually, option 1 will be fractionally faster, and use fractionally less memory, especially when called multiple times, or executed in a big loop; but it's a tradeoff between performance and readability

Comment: Could you point to where you obtained this information? I'm interested in knowing why there'd be any difference at all; won't PHP optimize away placeholder variables if not used in other contexts?

Comment: If he's returning it right away there should be no memory hit. Speedwise I'd think its up for negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is doing it right, these should all be the same once [tokenized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization). Assuming that's true, option two is the most readable and easiest to modify in the future. Perhaps [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like option one, as for your questions:

which is the best performance wise? Option One

What is considered best practice? Option One and Two depending on the complexity of the function.

But let's look at how they look as a function

Option One:

```
// Simple, readable
function optionOne($json) {
    return lowercaseKeys(json_decode(trim($json),true));
}
```

Option Two:

```
// Still readable with a little more detail to a novice developer
function optionTwo($json) {
    $trimmed = trim($json);
    $array   = json_decode($trimmed,true);
    $return  = lowercaseKeys($array);
    return $return;
}
```

Option Three:

```
// This might cause some problems with the $return variable
// Still looks like it would work but I'm not fond of this option
function optionThree($json) {
    $return = trim($json);
    $return = json_decode($return,true);
    $return = lowercaseKeys($return);
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I respect your opinion, but I have to disagree. Sticking all you can in a one liner, just to make it look more compact isn't necessarily good practice. To you it may look `readable`, but that's maybe because you're used to it, and tend to do that quite often. But if you work in a big team, where you have lots of new people coming in constantly, I don't think it's a very good coding standard - could in fact be daunting to some. I know this is a very basic one, but just speaking in general terms.

Comment: @xil3 understandable as I stated option two would be good for novice developers and I'm not for 'Sticking all you can in a one liner', but the function examples are using some basic php functions as trim() and json_decode() and I see no problem using them to format the object/var passed/returned to the function call itself. Now the lowercaseKeys() I might use option two but that all depends on the complexity of the function itself

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 will be maybe a microsecond faster than the other 2 options and use a few bits less physical memory, but any difference will be completely negligible unless multiplied on an exponential level. The core here is going to be the ultimate readability. I find Option 1 to be perfectly suitable personally, but I recognize that in some of the teams where I work, this option would not meet the standard for the lowest common denominator of developer. Option 2 and Option 3 really are exactly the same since you're not doing anything with the extra variables that are created. They both create 3 separate tokens. Option 2 is more explicitly readable in that the variables describe the method being applied at that stage, so I would vote for 2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do thing the 'option 2' way, myself. You never know when you might need something from half way through. Helps with readability too. Ok, it's not quite as efficient but for the sake of being able to understand and edit your code at a later date (especially if someone else has got to do it), option 2 feels best to me.

Answer (score 0):

I like the first option, and it use less memory but the difference is not significant